# Keycloak user federator

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I'm trying to put my new custom Federator in Keycloak so I've compiled my jar filed created using `mvn clean install` into `standalone/configuration/providers` following [this](http://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.1.0.Final/userguide/html/providers.html#d4e353) guide.

I then restarted the Wildfly 8 server but it doesn't seem to register my customer Federation provider.

Is there a reason why this isn't working?

Comment: Gonna need more info - can you perhaps list the contents of your .jar?  Which version of Keycloak you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Add a file

```
META-INF/services/org.keycloak.models.UserFederationProviderFactory
```

containing the full classname of your custom provider **factory**.
For example
be.abc.def.MyCustomProviderFactory

Restart Wildfly and the provider factory (not the provider itself) should be listed in the Users > Federation > Add provider dropdown by its id.