# Keycloak adding new user federator

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I tried to add my provider as to /opt/keycloak/providers/ as to /opt/keycloak/standalone/configuration/providers/

restart keycloak service, but I still have't seen my provider in dropdown list User Federation.

and META-INF/services/org.keycloak.models.UserFederationProviderFactory containing the full classname of your custom provider factory: org.keycloak.models.UserFederationProviderFactory

Please assist me

Comment: link for the same issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251672/keycloak-user-federator/43326303#43326303

Comment: have you tried deploying through the jboss admin console directly? ou can also try using the jboss-cli.sh module add command.